# Unable to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am getting cannot resolve FirebaseRecyclerAdapter when trying to use it even after adding firebase ui in gradle dependency.Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross-post: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show your `build.gradle` file?

Also, have you tried putting this under your package name in your java class: `import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;`?

Comment: If importing solved your problem, I would recommend pressing Ctrl + Shift + A and searching for "Auto Import". Open those settings and then check all the boxes under Java. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue, it's resolved by adding the firebase-ui dependency in build.gradle (module:app)

> compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

[image: Adding dependency in build.graddle (module:app)]

Also add the import in .java file where you're trying to declare it.

```
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to `build.gradle` file, add a dependency (get the latest one from here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

The latest one on 5 October 2019 is `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.0.2'`

Answer (score 2):

If You are facing Problem in 2020 then use this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.0.2'
```

above mentioned answers are not working in today's date i have tried all of them,remember import this package too:

```
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
```

Comment: You state that you have tried all of the previous answers, which is the right course before submitting a new answer. Yet, isn’t your Core answer identical to [@Anubhav-Mittal answer from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58250948/3025856)?

Answer (score 0):

In your app level gradle:add the following firebase dependency

```
    dependencies {
 compile'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies quoted above don't seem to work anymore. After about an hour of searching online, I found this; hopefully it helps someone. It certainly fixed my problem:

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'

Answer (score 0):

Use exactly the matched version of `FireBaseRecyclerAdapter`
to the Versions that you have included in gradle for the Firebase Database.
This link will surely help you

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

In this link, you will find the matched Firebase dependency according to the version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import the following three packages, and my problem is solved:

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In **June 2023**, it was the same problem for me. I was told about the version **6.2.1**, I don't whether it exists or not but I tried to downgrade it to **1.2.0** and it worked. I clearly don't know why, but I think its because I was using a version that didn't existed or was a version that was partially damaged or deleted.

Answer (score -2):

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
```

You can use this gradle dependencies

Comment: Please consider elaborating on this answer.