# error: cannot find symbol import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;

Tags: android, firebase

I have the right library and dependencies the build gradle(app) file. But I'm still etting this error.

According to some answers here, I have already tried all of them. I already checked if i have the right version, whether i have included the package correctly, whether the package name is same in google-service.json file, in manifest file, or in gradle file. I have already done all these.

// All google dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'
```

these are backdated on purpose.

as this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217164/11686135) suggests, i have already done that:

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

and this is the error its showing: Cannot resolve symbol 'database'

maybe somehow the dependencies not working...?
i am really novice at this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing a dependency, please refer to the

[GitHub project for FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android),

you might be missing just one more dependency such as any of these:

```
dependencies {
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'

// FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:5.0.0'

// FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0'

// FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:5.0.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if someone is getting same issue then try searching for Firebase Dependencies latest version

and add it issue will be resolved

**These are Latest dependencies add accordingly for use**

**To learn more**
[click here](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/)

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.3.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.3.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebaserecycleroption.

Basically android studio will change their version.
but build.gradle old dependencies are working in new version. So guys try to all dependecies in gradle.

gradle build dependencies:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2' 

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0'


//( Below two dependencies are same apply both )

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
```

( must try it )

Comment: Please format your code in the answer